# How to replace duplicate files with newer versions?

Tags: nautilus, backup, duplicate-files

I have several manual backups of the same folders, but when I backed them up I did not replace the older files with the newer ones. I simply made new folders, retaining the old and new backups. I've now got 2 terrabytes of backups that I have lost track of. 
I'd like to merge all the backup data into a single version of each file, retaining the new files only? The problem is that old and new files are now mixed up and not necessarily where they should be. Can this be fixed without CLI?

Comment: Without CLI? Why?

Comment: not a CLI addict